# How to chunkwise read and write with pandas and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm using python (version 3.4.4), pandas (version 0.19.1) and sqlalchemy (version 1.1.4) in order to chunkwise read from a large SQL table, preprocess those chunks and write them in a different SQL table. 
The continuous chunkwise read with `pd.read_sql_query(verses_sql, conn, chunksize=10)`, where `pd` is pandas import, `verses_sql` is the SQL query and `conn` is the DB-API connection, works fine if I do:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://<username>:<password>@<database>:1433/<FirstTable>')
conn = engine.connect()

verses_sql = '''SELECT [KA_Lang] FROM [dbo].[<FirstTable>]'''

for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(verses_sql, conn, chunksize=10):
    chunk['KA_Lang'] = chunk['KA_Lang'].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u02AF]'," ")
    chunk['KA_Lang'] = chunk['KA_Lang'].str.replace(r'\s\s+', " ")
    chunk['KA_Lang'] = chunk['KA_Lang'].str.lower()
    print(chunk['KA_Lang'].head(1))
```

Here is the problem: If I try to write the preprocessed chunks `chunk['KA_Lang']` in a second SQL table, let's call it `SecondTable`, only the **first** chunk of 10 elements is passed. The iteration stops there. Here is the adapted code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData

engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://<username>:<password>@<database>:1433/<FirstTable>')
conn = engine.connect()

verses_sql = '''SELECT [KA_Lang] FROM [dbo].[<FirstTable>]'''

for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(verses_sql, conn, chunksize=10):
    chunk['KA_Lang'] = chunk['KA_Lang'].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u02AF]'," ")
    chunk['KA_Lang'] = chunk['KA_Lang'].str.replace(r'\s\s+', " ")
    chunk['KA_Lang'] = chunk['KA_Lang'].str.lower()
    print(chunk['KA_Lang'].head(1))

    chunk.to_sql('<SecondTable>', conn, if_exists= 'append', index= False)

conn.close()
```

How do I continuously read one chunk from one SQL table and write it to a different SQL table? Why does the iteration through all chunks stops if I include: `chunk.to_sql('<SecondTable>', conn, if_exists= 'append', index= False)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of trying different workarounds, I solved this problem. It's fairly easy. For continuously reading one chunk from one SQL table and writing it to a different SQL table two different connection need to be defined:

```py
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://<username>:<password>@<database>:1433/<FirstTable>')
engine1 = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://<username>:<password>@<database>:1433/<FirstTable>')
conn = engine.connect()
conn1 = engine1.connect()
```

The line of code, where `chunk` is written in the second table, needs to be adapted to:

```py
chunk.to_sql('<SecondTable>', conn1, if_exists= 'append', index= False)
```

Done!